# JNA direct vs interface mapping?

Tags: jna

Sorry, this maybe a basic question. What are the difference between JNA direct mapping and interface mapping?

Is my interpretation correct:

- **Direct mapping**: use the library object directly (like static main in Java)
- **Interface mapping**: create an *instance* of the library object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Direct mapping directly binds your Java methods (declared with the `native` modifier) to native code which attempts to use the call stack as-is.  Direct mapping is most effective if you restrict your function arguments and return values to primitive types (the `Pointer` type may be considered primitive).

The interface mapping uses a `Proxy` and dynamically translates Java function signatures into a generic native entry point with a list of arguments which must subsequently be translated into native primitives.  It's more flexible w/r/t translating Java types to and from native, but can be much slower due to the runtime translation of arguments.